# how to convert substrings to quoted phrases with regex in JS script with modified boolean OR in bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, bookmarklet

I created a JS bookmarklet that prompts for a string that can be used on LinkedIn free people search (https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/). That website's Keywords field used to handle standard Boolean OR strings like

```
Keyword1 OR Keyword2 OR "keyword phrase3" OR "keyword phrase4" OR keyword5 OR keyword6
```

But it no longer supports standard boolean ORs beyond 5 terms. However, LinkedIn can handle long strings if the syntax is changed to:

```
Keyword1 OR(Keyword2) OR("keyword phrase3") OR("keyword phrase4") OR(keyword5) OR(keyword6)
```

So this script (syntax formatted like a bookmarklet because it's for non-technical end users who will be prompted for input) needs to:

- accept inputs like the very first string above (which may or may not include the ORs but we can assume they're needed if missing) and return output like second string above, and
- auto-insert the modified Boolean OR( syntax in the right places (i.e., only before the first term in a quoted multiword phrase if the user enters something like Keyword1 Keyword2 "keyword phrase3" "keyword phrase4" keyword5 keyword6

All I have working at the moment is converting single-term (non-quoted) inputs into proper syntax with regex & replace:

```
javascript:(function (){ var rgxstart, s, t;if(window.getSelection){s=window.getSelection();}else{s=document.selection.createRange().text;}t=prompt('This will run a LinkedIn free search for whatever terms appear here (optional to edit field contents before pressing Enter key):',s);if(t){t = t.trim(); rgxstart = /\b\s/gm; t = t.replace(rgxstart, ") OR("); t = t+')'; void(location='https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords='+escape(t)+'');}else{void(s);}  })();
```

I found this regex on StackOverflow to select only phrases (including the quotation marks)

```
(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1
```

which works fine on a tester like Regex101.com, but when I add that to the script like this:

```
javascript:(function (){ var rgxstart, s, t;if(window.getSelection){s=window.getSelection();}else{s=document.selection.createRange().text;}t=prompt('This will run a LinkedIn free search for whatever terms appear here (optional to edit field contents before pressing Enter key):',s);if(t){t = t.trim(); rgxphrase = /(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1/gm; t = t.replace(rgxphrase, ") OR("); t = t+')'; void(location='https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords='+escape(t)+'');}else{void(s);}  })();
```

It generates unwanted results: e.g., it takes input of

```
react "full stack" node.js "back end" developer
```

and

```
returns react ) OR( node.js ) OR( developer)
```

I realize it needs some kind of fancy regex lookarounds to detect if an upcoming term is not the first term within parentheses are needed, in order to know whether to insert an end-parentheses before the next word boundary, but this is way beyond my RegEx skillset.

How do I get script criteria #1 and 2 functioning?

Comment: I can't get that to work on regex101.com. https://regex101.com/r/7reLSN/1 Do you have a link for your successful use?

Comment: Yes, Barmar, I just saved it to https://regex101.com/r/BPgl9R/1 where you can see "full stack" and "front end" are the only matched examples in javascript "full stack" "front end" backend react node.js

Comment: Your example is missing the replacement part. When I add that, it shows an incorrect result: https://regex101.com/r/BPgl9R/3

Comment: I see your error but I don't know how to address the replacement part (which is partly why I submitted this SO question). It even seems to be giving trincot some problems (his revisions to the code so far still haven't addressed my earlier concern).

Comment: This kind of thing is not easy to do with regexp.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regular expression to match quoted strings and unquoted words

```
".*?"|\S+
```

You could use this as an argument to `match`:

```
.match(/".*?"|\S+/g)
```

Be aware that if you use this as part of a script that is encoded inside an HTML attribute, like `href="..."`, you'll need to encode those quotation marks:

```
.match(/&quot;.*?&quot;|\S+/g)
```

To accommodate that the user might enter some "or" already, those can be removed at the start of the process with `.replace(/ or /gi, ' ')`.

Here is the proposed script in a readable way (without encoding):

```js
var t = prompt('This will run a LinkedIn free search for whatever terms appear here (optional to edit field contents before pressing Enter key):',
               getSelection ? getSelection() : document.selection.createRange().text);
if (t) 
    location = 'https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords='
       + encodeURIComponent(
            t.replace(/ or /gi, ' ')
             .trim()
             .match(/".*?"|\S+/g)
             .map(function (w, i) { return i ? 'OR('+w+')' : w })
             .join(' ')
         );
```

In encoded form, with the anonymous function wrapper, ready to be put in an HTML attribute:

```
javascript:void(function(){var t=prompt('This will run a LinkedIn free search for whatever terms appear here (optional to edit field contents before pressing Enter key):',getSelection?getSelection():document.selection.createRange().text);if(t)location='https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords='+encodeURIComponent(t.replace(/ or /gi, ' ').trim().match(/&quot;.*?&quot;|\S+/g).map(function(w, i){return i?'OR('+w+')':w}).join(' '))}());
```

Here is a snippet that uses this code to *display* the URL that would be navigated to:

```js
var t = prompt('This will run a LinkedIn free search for whatever terms appear here (optional to edit field contents before pressing Enter key):',
               getSelection ? getSelection() : document.selection.createRange().text);
if (t) 
    loc.textContent = 'https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords='
       + encodeURIComponent(
            t.replace(/ or /gi, ' ')
             .trim()
             .match(/".*?"|\S+/g)
             .map(function (w, i) { return i ? 'OR('+w+')' : w })
             .join(' ')
         );
```

```html
<div id="loc"></div>
```

Comment: I think this is really close (& thx for fast response) but the problem is it doesn't handle multiword phrases well. For example: java "full stack" "front end" backend react node.js is turned into
java OR("full) OR(stack") OR("front) OR(end") OR(backend) OR(react) OR(node.js) but it needs to be  java OR("full stack") OR("front end") OR(backend) OR(react) OR (node.js)

Comment: In other words, trincot, can you edit your answer so it addresses how to treat two (or more) words between quotation marks as one unit to be prepended by OR(  (and it appears I mistyped the end of my previous comment- should have ended OR(node.js) but you probably realized that.

Comment: Reverted my answer back to what I had posted first. That look-behind regex was a bad idea that I had rushed in.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to revisit, trincot, but I still see the same error (whether using the anonymous function wrapper version or pasting/running the expanded code block in the console - e.g., java "full stack" "front end" react node.js is turned into
java OR("full) OR(stack") OR("front) OR(end") OR(react) OR(node.js) instead of java OR("full stack") OR("front end") OR(react) OR(node.js)

Comment: Please run the snippet. When I input `java "full stack" "front end" react node.js` I get `java%20OR(%22full%20stack%22)%20OR(%22front%20end%22)%20OR(react)%20OR(node.js)`. This seems correct. I have also tried again with the onliner `javascript:` link by putting it as a `href` attribute value and then clicked on that link. Also works like above. I'm sorry I cannot help you more. From the output you give in your latest comment, it looks like you still have used a previous version of my answer.

Comment: Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ocfv1wmk/) where I tested the `<a href="javascript:....">` solution. I can only see that it correctly translates the input to the URL with quoted words kept together.

Comment: Very strange. I just used the code from yourfiddle (starting with javascript: and ending with final semicolon) and the same kind of result I had before occurs, e.g., "back end" javascript "full stack" "front end" react is being converted to "back OR(end") OR(javascript) OR("full) OR(stack") OR("front) OR(end") OR(react) -- I will examine in other directions. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Did you run the fiddle at the link I provided in my previous comment (https://jsfiddle.net/ocfv1wmk/)? I just did it now and entered your last example, and it navigates to this URL: https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=%22back%20end%22%20OR(javascript)%20OR(%22full%20stack%22)%20OR(%22front%20end%22)%20OR(react) Are you telling me that little snippet doesn't work for you?

Comment: unfortunately, that's exactly what I'm telling you. I just created a completely new bookmarklet with the code in your fiddle (obviously minus the click me part) for "full stack" "front end" react angular and I'm redirected to https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=%22full%20OR(stack%22)%20OR(%22front)%20OR(end%22)%20OR(react)%20OR(angular)&sid=8X3  so if you see the proper result, then I'm at a loss about what's going on. I'm on the current version of Chrome browser.